# Flutter : How to view sqflite content for debugging in vscode

Tags: flutter, sqlite, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

there is any vscode extension to view the sqflite content?

in android studio I think there is a **Database Inspector** , what about vs code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following:

- VSCode-SQLite
- SQLite Viewer
- SQLite Database Browser